# How to load mapinfo file into geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, mapinfo, geopandas

I suspect this is a trivial question to answer but how do I load mapinfo mid/mif files into geopandas?

While it's trivial to load and manipulate .shp files, I can't work out what code to use:

Here's a few examples of the data I'm trying to play with: http://www.stoke.gov.uk/ccm/content/business/general/open-geospatial-consortium-data-catalogue.en

```
cylpaths = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file(path)
```

I tried to test the geometry, which shows:

```
cylpaths.crs

 Out[15]:
{u'ellps': u'airy',
 u'k': 0.9996012717,
u'lat_0': 49,
u'lon_0': -2,
u'no_defs': True,
u'proj': u'tmerc',
u'towgs84': u'375,-111,431,-0,-0,-0,0',
u'units': u'm',
u'x_0': 400000,
u'y_0': -100000}
```

But when I try to preview the data, I get an empty dataframe:

```
cylpaths

Out[16]:
Int64Index([], dtype='int64')   Empty GeoDataFrame
```

I'm a bit lost in working out what I need to do next.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I'm writing this answer, the original question is 7 years old, but it might make sense to address.

The current version of `GeoPandas` does include out-of-the-box support for MapInfo files. This is actually handled by the `Fiona` library. Check the snippet of code below:

```py
import fiona

# Checks if GeoPandas can read MapInfo files
print('MapInfo File' in fiona.supported_drivers)
```

The code above **should** print out `True`. If so, it means that your setup is ready to read MapInfo files. If not, you might have to reinstall `Fiona`.

In case your setup is MapInfo-ready, you can use the code chunk below to read in [this sample data](http://e-ots.com/MapInfoData/US_Counties.zip).

```py
import geopandas as gpd

tab_file = 'US_CNTY.TAB'

tab_data = gpd.read_file(tab_file)
```

At this point, `tab_data` is an easy-to-manipulate `GeoDataFrame`.

I hope this answers things!